# Orbits/affine spaces in GAP

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions, gap

Another GAP-related question.

I need to compute the orbits of a lot (probably, hundreds of thousands) groups acting on $\mathbb{F}_2$-vectors spaces of dimension 23 or 22. The groups range from (almost) the full automorphism group of the Leech lattice down to something of size 4 or 2. (Obviously, this is done in a batch, so I cannot tune this manually.) In fact, instead of the whole space I need an affine subspace of the form $v\cdot k\ne0$ for a certain invariant covector $k$ known in advance. What is statistically the most efficient way of doing that? Currently, I'm creating a vector space

```
V := VectorSpace(...);
```

and then struggling between

```
V := Filtered(V, ...);
V := OrbitsDomain(G, V);
```

in the hope that smaller list is better, or, in the hope that "structured" methods would be more efficient than those for plain lists,

```
V := OrbitsDomain(G, V);
V := Filtered(V, ...);
```

Both are quite slow (typically, about .5 to 1 min each action) and, for some reason, after quite a few test runs I couldn't get any conclusive comparison results: on the same input, time varies from run to run and there seems to be no definite winner. Can someone who knows the details of the implementation tell me which should "typically" work best? Or is there something else totally different that I'm not aware of?

P.S. I tried converting the matrix group action to permutations first, too, but that seems to be definitely slower.

Comment: Wouldn't that belong to computational geometric invariant theory, like investigated by Valiant and then Mulmuley-Sohoni, and Landsberg, and for sure Sturmfels must have worked in the field too ? I have no clue what they do. It's just the outer shell of your question looks like matching that.

Comment: In my mmgroup package function mmgroup.leech2_orbits_raw() essentially does that job for orbits of subgroups of the Conway group $\mbox{Co}_1$ (given by a set of generators) on the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^{24}$. For documentation see
https://mmgroup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-mmgroup.structures.xleech2.
The underlying C program is a highly optimized union-find algorithm which usually takes less than a second for a group generated by, say, 10 elements. I think it is not too difficult to adjust that algorithm to your problem.

Comment: Great! Thanks, Martin! I'll take a look right away.